# How can one modify the outline color of a node In networkx?

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes, nodes, networkx

I am relatively new to networkx and plotting using matplotlib.pyplot and would like to know how to modify the color (or other attributes such as weight) of a node's outline. By "outline" I don't mean an arc or edge between two nodes; I mean the thin black line around the circle that is by default used to represent a node when plotting a network.

So for example, when I make a graph that has just a single node and display it:

```
from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
G = Graph()
G.add_node(1)
draw(G)
```

I see a single red node with a thin black outline (and a black "1" inside it, which is the node's label). How can I change the color of that outline from black to, say, red ("#FF0000"), or another color? Alternatively, can I suppress the display of the outline entirely?

I'm imagining there must be an attribute, analogous to edge_color or node_color, that I can set. However, I was not able to find such an attribute via a web search, in the networkx documentation, or by looking at gallery examples. If someone can point me to the appropriate attribute(s) that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `draw` calls `draw_networkx` see http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx, you can set the `edge_color` param to whatever you like

Comment: `edge_color` only sets the graph edge color, while the question refers to the node outlines (comparable to `marker_edge_color` or `mec` for line graphs in pyplot). I'm looking, but haven't yet found a good solution...

Comment: @surfreak Ah yes, sorry my mistake, don't have an answer immediately then, will dig around

Comment: Since NetworkX 2.1, there's an `edgecolors` argument added to `draw_networkx_nodes()` as stated [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016020).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**UPDATE (3/2019)**: [as of networkx 2.1, the kwargs are forwarded](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx) from `draw()`, so you should be able to simply call `draw()` with the `edge_color` kwarg.

Ok, this is kind of hacky, but it works. Here's what I came up with.

**The Problem**

`networkx.draw()` calls `networkx.draw_networkx_nodes()`, which then calls `pyplot.scatter()` to draw the nodes. The problem is that the keyword args accepted by `draw_networkx_nodes()` aren't passed on to `scatter()`. ([source here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes))

---

To solve this, I basically broke apart `networkx.draw()` into its components: `draw_networkx_nodes`, `draw_networkx_edges`, and `draw_networkx_labels`.

**The Solution**

We can take the return value of `draw_networkx_nodes()` -- a `PathCollection` -- and operate on that: you can use `PathCollection.set_edgecolor()` or `PathCollection.set_edgecolors()` with either a color or a list, respectively.

Example code:

```
from networkx import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G = Graph()
G.add_node(1)
# Need to specify a layout when calling the draw functions below
# spring_layout is the default layout used within networkx (e.g. by `draw`)
pos = spring_layout(G)
nodes = draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos)
# Set edge color to red
nodes.set_edgecolor('r')
draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
# Uncomment this if you want your labels
## draw_networkx_labels(G, pos)
plt.show()
```

If you're going to be using this a lot, it probably makes more sense (IMO) to just redefine `draw_networkx_nodes` to actually pass the kwargs to `scatter`. But the above *will* work.

To remove the marker edges entirely, simply set the color to `None` instead of `'r'`.

Comment: Does anyone see a reason why the kwargs **shouldn't** be passed to scatter? If not, I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Please do submit a bug report.  I think the kwargs weren't passed to avoid conflict/confusion of similar arguments to draw_networkx_edges() etc.  The drawing interface to matplotlib is crufty and could use a proper design.

Comment: Thanks, @surfreak, for the explanation and example code. Never have I been so happy to see a small red dot (i.e., you're right, it works).

Comment: @Aric: agreed that the drawing interface could use some work, although mine is the opinion of a noob.

Comment: @user1071516 You can directly access the PathCollection object when using nx.draw(), see my answer below.

Comment: @surfreak, In 2.2 there is also the karg `edgecolors` for `draw_networkx_nodes()`.

Comment: I think the update to this answer is wrong. `edge_color` argument in `draw()` sets the color of the edges = links in the graph, not the edges of the nodes

Answer (score 24):

Since [NetworkX 2.1](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/), there's an `edgecolors` argument added to [`draw_networkx_nodes()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html)(as well as to [`draw()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.1/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw) since it ultimately calls `draw_networkx_nodes()` to draw nodes).

Comment: How to make fill color transparente but not edge color?

Comment: @Sigur Set the `node_color` keword argument to the `draw()` function to be the same as your background colour. Let's say your background colour is white and you want nodes with just a black border. Then you could call `nx.draw(G, pos, node_color='#FFFFFF', edgecolors='#000000')`

Comment: It's worth noting: the `edgecolors` keyword argument (for setting the outline of nodes) is different from the `edge_color` keyword argument (for setting the colour of lines).

Answer (score 18):

If you want to change the color of the nodes' outline, you can just do:

```
draw(G, linewidths=2)
ax = plt.gca() # to get the current axis
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#FF0000")
```

And that's it.

- `ax.collections[0]` is a `PathCollection` object governing the **nodes**
- `ax.collections[1]` is a `LineCollection` object governing the **edges** if you have some.

You can modify many other properties rapidly with a given collection.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an antient thread, but I was looking for this answer too, and finally found the native non-hacky way. You can pass the argument linewidths=0 into the draw function. I think this only affects the width of the node borders rather than the edge width (which is controled by width=x).

Comment: This is the way, thanks, it's only strange they didn't give the parameter a better name

Comment: Strangely, although I clearly thought this answer was very helpful last year, encountering the same issue now, I can't make sense of it